# Four-parameter Beta distribution and Wikipedia

Tags: probability-distributions

Sorry if it is not an appropriate place for such questions, but anyway can anybody please confirm that the formula for the density function of the four-parameter Beta distribution is correct in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Four_parameters). It seems $(c - a)$ is missing in the denominator. Thank you.

Best regards,
Ivan

Comment: Such questions are ok; there was a discussion about (more-or-less) similar questions: [Questions concerning editing of wikipedia articles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2771/questions-concerning-editing-of-wikipedia-articles).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the factor is indeed missing.

Let $X$ be standard 2-parameter Beta random variable. The four-parameter one $Y$ is obtained by affine transformation $Y = (c-a) X + a$ for $c>a$. Then
$$
   f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{c-a} f_X\left(\frac{y-a}{c-a}\right) = \frac{1}{c-a} \left(\frac{y-a}{c-a} \right)^{\alpha-1} \left(\frac{c-y}{c-a} \right)^{\beta-1} \frac{\mathbf{1}(a < y <c)}{B(\alpha,\beta)} = 
   \frac{(y-a)^{\alpha-1} (c-y)^{\beta-1}}{(c-a)^{\alpha+\beta-1}}\frac{\mathbf{1}(a < y <c)}{B(\alpha,\beta)}
$$

Comment: Thanks. If anybody knows how to fix it in Wikipedia, can you please do it?

Comment: @Ivan: Done. It's straightforward to contribute to Wikipedia, by the way; just click on the "edit" link; you can fix things without registering if you want.

Comment: @joriki : I was about to say all you need to do is click on "edit" and then edit, but I see you beat me to it.  I've actually heard professors say they'd like to change things in Wikipedia articles but they don't know how.